# REACT 16 (cdn) with REDUX error

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using CDN link without NPM to build my react application

when i try to call Provider and Connect

```
var Provider = ReactRedux.Provider;
var connect = ReactRedux.connect;
```

thats why i have to call redux library

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/3.5.2/redux.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/4.4.5/react-redux.js" ></script>
```

**it works** when i use react **version 15** as below

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.6.1/dist/react.js"></script> 
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.6.1/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
```

**but when i updated to  react version 16 , it shows error**

**Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactRedux is not defined**

```
<script  src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script  src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[Error msg pic here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obTFH.gif)